# I got this error message while trying to get my position in react native:

Tags: react-native, expo

in the device:
Error while updating property 'corrdinate' of view maneg by: AIRMapMarker
in the console terminal:
ERROR  Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `coordinate.latitude` is marked as required in `MapMarker`, but its value is `null`.

my code:

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Context from "../../global/Context";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import * as Position from "expo-location";
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const Location = (props) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const { states } = useContext(Context);
  const place = states.place;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Position.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

      if (status !== "granted") {
        setErrorMsg("App não tem permissão para acessar localizaçõa");
      }

      let location = await Position.getCurrentPositionAsync();
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = "Carregando...";
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      source={require("../../img/mypoint-wallpaper.jpg")}
    >
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
          }}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: place.latitude,
            longitude: place.longitude,
            longitudeDelta: 0.01,
            latitudeDelta: 0.01,
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: place.latitude,
              longitude: place.longitude,
            }}
          />

          <Marker
            title="Sua localização"
            coordinate={{
              latitude: location && location.coords.latitude,
              longitude: location && location.coords.longitude,
            }}
          />
        </MapView>
        <Text style={styles.txtStyle}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    </ImageBackground>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To Draw a marker longitude and latitude is must and are required props.
your latitude and longitude is null here

```
   <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: place.latitude,
                    longitude: place.longitude
                }}/>
```

so draw the marker only when you have coordinates
use something like this :-

```
{(place.latitude && place.longitude) ? <Marker
                coordinate={{
                    latitude: place.latitude,
                    longitude: place.longitude
                }}/> : null
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot I was tryin to do that making a conditional at the coordinate attribute when it was required to draw all marker.
Thanks again